# Get DataMapper Model Properties

Tags: ruby, datamapper

Is there a way to get the properties of a model with DataMapper? For example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'datamapper'

class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
end
```

Could I get the properties of `User` in an array or a hash?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can get them with

```
User.properties
```

it will return an instance of PropertySet which you can cast into an Array if you want.

Comment: does this still work? I'm on datamapper 1.2.0 and it appears `.properties` is now a private method. Also, it's now `require 'data_mapper'`. Any idea what the new way to obtain properties might be?

Comment: Every time I use this, I get `#`'s. e.g. I go Blog.properties.inspect and it's `[#,#,#,#,#]` for `class Blog
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id,         Serial
    property :slug,       String, :length => 25  
    property :title,      String, :length => 75
    property :content,    Text
    property :created_at, Time
end`

tried to `.to_s` `each` property as well and it only shows me `#`'s. Any ideas how to get the actual property names? e.g. `id, slug, title, content, created_at` ?

Comment: btw, this is what I'm talking about when I say that it is private: https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/master/lib/dm-core/property.rb#L672

Answer (score 3):

```
>> u = User.new
=> #<User @id=nil @name=nil>
>> u.id = 1
=> 1
>> u.name = "hello"
=> "hello"
>> u.attributes
=> {:name=>"hello", :id=>1}
>> u.attributes.class
=> Hash
```